# Fixed navbar with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to change the navbar in my child theme but I'm a newbie. I read some questions here about that and even saw the bootstrap site, but I don't understand how to solve my problem. I'm sorry for my ignorance but could someone explain to me how it works?

I'm using this theme http://demos.codexcoder.com/#limo_wp and I would like to fixed the navbar instead of this "blink" and float. Just stay fixed after scroll the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find an example on the bootstrap website.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Or you can change

```
<section id="headnev" class="navbar topnavbar">
```

to

```
<section id="headnev" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
```

in your header file and remove:

```
// Script for top Navigation Menu
    jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function () {
      if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        jQuery('#headnev').addClass('navbar-fixed-top').removeClass('topnavbar');
        jQuery('body').addClass('bodytopmargin').removeClass('bodynomargin');
      } else {
        jQuery('#headnev').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top').addClass('topnavbar');
        jQuery('body').removeClass('bodytopmargin').addClass('bodynomargin');
      }
    });
```

from custom.js

Comment: This solution totally removes the unwanted functionality from your theme so why wasn't it market as the answer?

Answer (score 3):

**The following command:**

[Fixed to top:](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)
Add `.navbar-fixed-top` and include a `.container` or `.container-fluid` to center and pad navbar content.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        ...
    </div>
</nav>
```

If you want to fixed menu after scroll the page. You use fllowing javascript code. In this code fixed menu after if scrolls over a specific element. I wrote the following code based on your template.

```
<script>
    if ( $('body').scrollTop() > $('.section-a').position.top ) {
         $('#headnev').removeClass('topnavbar');
         $('#headnev').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, @AHIR ! I recently noticed that once I did this I accomplished my goal but when I chose the mobile version of visualization, the menu doesn't work. Any ideas why is that happening?

Comment: Hi @U23r Did you call dropdown.js in your theme?

Comment: This call would be in my header.php, right? If yes, then, no. It didn't call any dropdown.js
When I click the menu on mobile version, it does nothing. It is like the button was disabled or something.

Comment: @U23r You should call `dropdown.js` after `jquery-*.js` in header or footer.

Answer (score 3):

just add a `class="nav navbar navbar-fixed-top"`

I'll give you an example of my code, just use it and see how it works.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <div class="navbar-brand"><a href="nature.html">Project Nature</a></div>

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active dropdown">

                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Nature <b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#"><a href="#">Plants</a></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><a href="#">Landscapes</a></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><a href="#">Animals</a></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><a href="#">Elements</a></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>

                <li class="dropdown">

                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Media <b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#"><a href="#">Twitter</a></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><a href="#">Facebook</a></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><a href="#">Google+</a></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><a href="#">LinkedIn</a></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

This will generate a navbar with a heading (title)
5 menu items of wich 2 are dropdowns.

Greetings :)

Comment: also should you add a margin-top to the body of the height of your navbar, or on your container,  that's something I don't know for sure

Answer (score 3):

You could try my css also, simple yet effective if you are positioning it always on the top

```
.navbar{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 1000000;
    top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add something like the following CSS to a child theme to override this behavior in the parent theme.

```
#header .navbar {
    animation:none !important;
}
```

If you aren't familiar with WordPress child themes, [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) is a good resource for you. There may even be a theme setting for this. Depends on what the theme developer made available in the theme's options.

Comment: It doesn't work, but thanks for trying. @AHIR 's solution worked well.

Comment: Did you try it? I tested it in inspect element and it worked fine according to my understanding of what you described. Perhaps your description was  not clear enough. "Blink" is not a very good description of UI behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

In the `navbar` `div`, you should add the class name `.navbar-fixed-top`.