# Whats wrong with my navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap, and when I scroll down, my navbar just goes away. (Even though it follows for a bit. It's easier to put it on my test site than to post screenshots. http://dev.melmsie.com/

If you need code here instead of inspecting the site, let me know.

**Bonus**: Also, why is my main picture (the wild-flowers) missing a bit on the right? (I see white)

**Edit**: Ignore the rest of the site, it's only ~50% done

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="main-section">
      <nav class=" navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="headers-bfg">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BFG</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-header">
                 <a class="navbar-brand col-xs-2" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class=" nav navbar-nav ">
              <li><a href="#">Balloons</a></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-small fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
              <li><a href="#">Flowers</a></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
              <li><a href="#">Gifts</a></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
              <li><a href="#">Hours</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </nav>



.navbar {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}

.nav {
float: right;
text-align: left;
font-size: 20px;
letter-spacing: .5px;
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to just add the code for the navbar if you could.

Comment: @the_grits done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add z-index for this rule CSS.

```
.navbar {
  z-index: 9000000;
}
```

If you want more details about **z-index** seeing this documentation [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Comment: Yeah this is good if you don't intend to use any modals or anything else a lower z-index is fine. Just keep in mind it should be indeed set high enough to always stay on top of other elements.

Comment: I agree with you, because if it has modals or something else, he must make the order in the z-index

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just override the behavior you can add a z-index to the following css to .nabar

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you wanna set your navbar at the top, and that the users always see the navbar even with the scroll down, right?

Have you tried this?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

You can see a [full explanation right here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29706526/6045792)

I hope I've helped., if not, let know.

Answer (score 1):

For the nav-bar it seems perfectly fine. It does not go away for me or anything. With the image, I was able to pinpoint the location of it. If you go to your "/css/bfg.css" find `.main-section`, his is where you have the background image and you've set it up how you like it, great! All you need to do is edit the width on your `.main-section` image, http://dev.melmsie.com/img/back.jpg. To make it easy add 10% more width so you don't have to keep editing the width since it is a small area that you're missing.

Just by the looks of your unfinished website it is fabulous!
J. Carter :)

Answer (score 0):

simply added z-index. You need to add it into .navbar class, have a look code.

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

As for as image, If you want to show full image when place it inside the container. you are using full width image which should like as it now.